# How to retrieve the master ChannelID in CustomHandlers onDataRead method

Tags: java, netty

For logging purpose I need to get the used listener `ChannelID` in overriden the `onDataRead` method of my handler.

At the Inbound log I see the right id. (See below). But when I try to get the id like this:

```
 public void onDataRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Http2DataFrame data) throws Exception {
    if (data.isEndStream()) {
        System.out.println(ctx.channel().id());
}   }
```

This will print another id than it shows in my log below:

Inbound log:

```
----------------INBOUND--------------------
[id: 0x73888d9b, L:/127.0.0.1:8080 - R:/127.0.0.1:6624] HEADERS: streamId=5, headers=DefaultHttp2Headers[:path: test/, :method: POST, :scheme: http, :authority: 127.0.0.1:8080, accept-encoding: gzip, accept-encoding: deflate], streamDependency=0, weight=16, exclusive=false, padding=0, endStream=false
------------------------------------
```

What could be the reason for a different id in `ChannelHandlerContext`? When in the inbound log a different id is shown? How can I get the same id as shown in the inbound log?

Answer (score 1):

After a few hours of reading the javadoc i found the following method to find the parent channel (and it's id)

```
ctx.channel().parent().id());
```